# How to access a std::vector data from a templated class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to implement a templated class that has a vector container from the standard library as a member. The purpose of the class is to create a linear algebra class for my personal use.

The class is supposed to have a constructor that initializes a vector filled only with zeros and two overloadings of the `[]` operator to access the data.

The code looks as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>class LinAlg
{
private:
    std::vector<T> mVector;
    int mSize;
public:
    LinAlg(int size);
    T & operator[](int i); 
    T const & operator[] (int i)const;
};

template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    std::vector<T> mVector;
    for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
    {
        mVector.push_back(0);
    }
}

template<class T> T &  LinAlg<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    return mVector[i];
}

template<class T> T const& LinAlg<T>::operator[](int i)const
{
    return mVector[i];
}

int main()
{
  LinAlg<double> vec(2);
  vec[0] = 1.0; 
  vec[1] = 1.0; 
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
      std::cout << vec[i] << '\n'; 
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently, the code compiles correctly, but there is no output from the main function. The problem appears to be in the overloading of the operators and I have been reading in different forums but I haven't been able to find the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are declaring a new local variable `std::vector<T> mVector;` in your constructor.

Comment: Advice -- don't use extraneous variables such as `mSize` to determine the number of entries in a vector.  A vector knows its size by calling the vector's `size()` function.  Using extraneous variables to keep track of the size can only lead to bugs occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    std::vector<T> mVector; // <- oops
    for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
    {
        mVector.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

`std::vector<T> mVector;` defines a new variable `mVector` [that shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the member variable `mVector`. The local `mVector` effectively replaces the member `mVector` and is initialized, loaded with 0s and then discarded when the constructor ends. The member `mVector` is left [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) to size zero, causing problems later on when you attempt to access the values you believe you stored.

Instead you could

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    // std::vector<T> mVector;  <- remove this
    for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
    {
        mVector.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

but `std::vector` has a constructor that does this work for you, default initializing `size` elements, that you can take advantage of in the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size):
    mVector(size), mSize(size)
{
}
```

Further, since `std::vector` knows its length, you can remove the `mSize` member and replace uses of it with `mVector.size()`

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor, you are declaring a local variable `mVector` that hides the class member of the same name.  So you are populating the local variable, not the class member.  You need to remove the local variable:

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
    {
        mVector.push_back(0);
    }
}
```

Now, that being said, you don't need the loop at all, since `std::vector` has a `resize()` method that can fill the vector with values:

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
{
    mSize = size;
    mVector.resize(size); // <-- will set new elements to 0 by default
}
```

Alternative, you can use the vector's own constructor instead, which does the same thing:

```
template<class T> LinAlg<T>::LinAlg(int size)
    : mVector(size) // <-- will set elements to 0 by default
{
    mSize = size;
}
```

Either way, the `mSize` member is redundant, as `std::vector` has its own `size()` method that you can use when needed.